# Standard DB table structure of web page additional content?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I have this page table structure to store all the website page information,

```
page_id
page_url
page_title
page_subtitle
page_description
page_introduction
page_content_1
page_content_2
page_content_3
page_content_4
...
```

You can see that I have `page_content_1` to `page_content_4`, instead of just `page_content`. The reason why I do this because I might want to store different types of page content for each page.

But I doubt whether this is a good practice or not? What if other developer comes to further develop on this page table, would you find this structure redundant?

I am thinking maybe I should create another table to store additional page content like this below?

table `page_additional_content`,

```
content_id
content_additional_1
content_additional_2
content_additional_3
content_additional_4
page_id
```

Is this better?

Or there is better standard idea that I should look into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on Quentin's answer, if you want to be able to reuse content across pages (such as headers or footers), you could create a table structure like:

```
page_content: 
     content_id (primary key)
     actual_content (actual content of the page)
page_structure: 
     page_id (foreign key of the page)
     content_id (foreign key of the content)
     order_in_page (order of the content in the page)
```

You content can grow to as many sections as you want without adding additional tables (just add a new row in page_structure and increment the order_in_page counter).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dante. I am a bit confused with your suggestion. Do you mean that I can do this just in on table which is all in the actual content table, and the additional table is not really needed? thanks.

Comment: No, you would still need two tables. The page_content table would just have an identifier and the HTML content of that section (what you originally had in your page_content_1, page_content_2, ... tables). The page_structure would be a table that defines an actual page and tracks which page section appears on the page, and in what order.

Comment: You could also put your content_additional_# data inside the page_content table.

Comment: I think I am getting there! so where do I keep the columns of `page_id`, `page_url`, `page_title` as there is no `page_id` in your table of `page_content` (the primary key is `content_id`) ? Another table for `page_id`, `page_url`, `page_title`, etc?

Comment: You would still have your regular page table that will hold the page_id (the primary key, which would be used in page_structure), the page_url, etc. Those properties are one-to-one, so they work well in a field. The page_structure table will just be a map from the page table to the page_content table that says "this page is made up of these content items in this order."

Comment: Thank you very much for the further explanation. I am totally clear now! lol

Answer (score 0):

When you start having columns with the same name, but with a numerical suffix then you should usually start thinking "New table + foreign key".

You would probably be better off with something along the lines of a content table structured like:

```
document_id  |  page  |  content
1            |  1     |  foo, bar, baz
```